# how to design scoreboard?

Tags: html, design

I developed an online exam using .net and now I want to send score to mail. But I want it look like a certificate. How should I design it, or alternatively, are there any template designs available

Comment: This question has been reopened on Stack Overflow, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800347/how-to-design-scoreboard

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">
/*<![CDATA[*/
<!--
a {text-decoration:none; font-size: 150pt}
a:link {color: blue;}
a:visited {color: blue;}
a:hover {color: blue;}
a:active {color: blue;}//-->
/*]]>*/
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var x=0;

function up() {
    ++x;
    y = x.toString();
        if (y < 10) {
        y = "0"+y;
    }
    document.getElementById('tens').innerHTML = y.substr(0,1);
    document.getElementById('ones').innerHTML = y.substr(1);
}
function down() {
    --x;
    y = x.toString();
        if (y < 10) {
        y = "0"+y;
    }
    document.getElementById('tens').innerHTML = y.substr(0,1);
    document.getElementById('ones').innerHTML = y.substr(1);
}
//]]>
</script>
```

try that

```
<a href="#" id="tens" onmousedown="down()" name="tens">0</a><a href="#" id="ones" onmousedown="up()" name="ones">0</a>
```